File size from CRAM to fastq
so I have some WGS data, and I was given the cram and cram.crai; I want to change them to fastq I am using samtools:
samtools fastq -O -c 7 C-7507T.cram > C-7507T.fastq.gz
The cram file is 32G The fastq file is 583G
is that difference in size normal?
ps: most probably it is single end not pair end
samtools fastq -O -c 7 C-7507T.cram > C-7507T.fastq.gz

The difference in size between CRAM and FASTQ files is normal. CRAM files are more compact due to efficient compression, while FASTQ files include both sequence data and quality scores. In your case, the 32 GB CRAM file resulted in a 583 GB FASTQ file, reflecting the additional information stored in the latter format.
